# Play custom sound for push notification from audio file url

Tags: xcode, push-notification, xcode6.3

I want to send custom sound in push notification, the problem is that I won't be having file in bundle or documents directory, the url of the audio file will be coming with push notification. Is it possible to play sound from that url when the push notification arrives.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By coding, what have you tried?

Comment: I did a little R&D and found that custom sound can only be played when file is present in documents directory or in resources. I tried various way but since there methods called with Push notification only execute when app is launched I was unable to figure out on how to download the file when push notification comes becuase the url is in the body of that push notification. File will be of approx 700kb so it might take a little time. Will that delay push notification as well?